# Parental Controls on Ubuntu

Tags: parental-controls

I am wondering how I would set up parental controls on my personal computer. This should allow blocking of all adult websites and should enforce safe search. I am aware DansGuardian and Squid but will they work on a personal laptop, without using a service such as pfsense?

Comment: Please edit your question to include what "parental controls" you would like to be imposed on this computer.

Comment: Why the down votes ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool that will replace parental oversight and the problem with the tools you mention is that there are rarely an agreement between any 2 people on what is acceptable and for what age.

#### Web proxy

If you wish to install tools such as **squid** / **dansguardian** you then are responsible for configuration, maintenance, and monitoring.

For how I manage these services see [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20190830164841/http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/web-content-filtering-made-easy/)

#### DNS

An easier solution, IMO, by far is to use a [tool such as OpenDNS](https://www.howtogeek.com/201312/how-to-use-opendns-on-your-router-pc-tablet-or-smartphone/). OpenDNS is free, easier to configure, and then, once configured, they maintain white / black lists for you.

See also [this](https://www.geckoandfly.com/11638/free-parental-control-software/) and [this](http://www.cd-csd.org/SiteContent/documents/Technology/OpenDns%20Parental%20Controls.pdf).